# Store Login time and logout time when user click on button in Netbeans Database and display via JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, netbeans

I have created a Login Page. When User is logged in; it shows below screen. When User clicks 'User profile'. I want to show users access logs (User Id, login date/time, logout date/time). How do I store in Netbeans database and how do I delete and show the existing record from a view.

Can someone show an example or help me create my jsp, java and database in NETBEANS for user access logs.

[image]

Comment: could you post your code with what you have tried till now

Comment: NetBeans is not a database.

Comment: Please open the project in Netbeans. Google Drive Link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1b7WTSQ6XORz7qiyq41n2hCtx779V-yyv?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is very broad for this site. We’re bad at such high-level questions. You should at least try your search engine first (BTW, always do that before posting here). Try some of guidelines or advice you find. If something turns out not to work, come back here with a much more specific question. We’re good with those.

Comment: @SantdasRai try posting revelant code in your question .